# Google calendar API returning error in server

Tags: google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api, permission-denied, service-accounts

I have integrated the calendar API for adding a calendar invitation functionality in my application. and the same is working fine for me local. But when I move the code to the server, Google API is returning the following error

```
    {
"statusCode":500,
    "code":"403",
    "error":"Internal Server Error",
    "message":"Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."
    }
```

I use the same credentials in the server also. but that doesn't work for me. Is there any additional cases that can occur in the above case.

Below is my code snippet

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

// Google calendar API settings
const SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar',
];
const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3' });

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
    process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    null,
    process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY,
    SCOPES,
    process.env.CALENDAR_ADMIN,
    'api_key'
);

calendarInvite: async (
        title,
        eventType,
        host,
        club,
        startDateAndTime,
        endDateAndTime,
        attendees
    ) => {
        const description = `Hi,

         You are invited to attend the event.

         Thanks`;

        const subject = ` ${club.name} ${eventType.name}: ${title}`;
        const eventObj = {
            summary: subject,
            description: description,
            organizer: {
                email: host[0].email,
            },
            start: {
                dateTime: startDateAndTime,
                timeZone: process.env.TIME_ZONE,
            },
            end: {
                dateTime: endDateAndTime,
                timeZone: process.env.TIME_ZONE,
            },
            attendees: attendees,
            reminders: {
                useDefault: false,
                overrides: [
                    { method: 'email', minutes: 24 * 60 },
                    { method: 'popup', minutes: 10 },
                ],
            },
            conferenceData: {
                createRequest: {
                    conferenceSolutionKey: {
                        type: 'hangoutsMeet',
                    },
                    requestId: uuidv4(),
                },
            },
        };
        return calendar.events.insert({
            auth: auth,
            calendarId: 'primary',
            resource: eventObj,
            sendNotifications: true,
            sendUpdates: 'all',
            conferenceDataVersion: 1,
        });

    },
```

Apart from this, I have added the role **Service Account Token Creator** to the account.

I am not sure why it was working perfectly locally and not on the server.

Comment: Have you tried [delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)? If so, can you share with us how you did it so that we may track where you made a possible mistake?

Comment: you also need to deligate to a user on your workspace domain I don't see the deligation in your code

Comment: @DaImTo I wonder then how it was working local with the same credentials?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing but I am mobile right now and can't test your Code ☺️